# What is L-implication?

Tags: logic

So I'm reading *The GUHA Method of Automatic Hypothesis Determination* by P. Hajek, and he talks about something called "L-implication". Forgive the stupid question, but what does that mean? I'm not a math major, so please go easy on me.

While I'm on this, what do each of the other terms he uses mean:

1. L-true
2. L-false
3. factual
4. L-implication
5. L-equivalence

Here is how the author introduces these notions:
[image: guha]

As a follow up, there is a theorem that uses *L-implication*, which I have absolutely no idea what it talks about. Does he just mean "implied" when he says "L-implied"?

[image: theorem5]

P.S.: Don't now how to tag this aside from *logic*. I'm actually reading the paper for my data-mining background research.

Comment: I believe I could explain, if only I knew what $L$ is. What is $L$? These terms and passages make sense if $L$ is a theory, but then why 'L' rather than 'T'? A language? That makes less sense.

Comment: @BrianO: I think that is basically the OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no access to Hajek's paper, but it seems that the concepts your are asking for are the basic *(meta-)logical* concept:

> L-true means (logically) *valid*
>
> L-false means *contradictory*
>
> a formula that is neither L-true nor L-false is *factual*
>
> L-implication is *logical consequence*.

---

See :

- Rudolf Carnap, [Introduction to Symbolic Logic and its Applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=hAvVAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA15) (1958, German ed.1954 - Dover reprint), page 15 : **Ch.A.5. L-CONCEPTS**:

> let us introduce several concepts which are logical in the sense just indicated. We shall call them L-concepts, and shall form terms for them with the prefix "L-". [...] we say that a *sentential formula* is L-*true* just in case [...] it is true for every value-assignment.
>
> A sentential formula is said to be L-*false* (or logically false, or contradictory) in case [...] it is false for every value-assignment.

And see [ [page 19](https://books.google.it/books?id=hAvVAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA19) ] : **Ch.A.6. L-IMPLICATION AND L-EQUIVALENCE**.

Comment: The interpretation of "L" as "language" seems to be at odds with the fact that the images use an _upright_ L rather than an italic $L$, which it would be if it were a variable referring to a particular language. It also really doesn't make sense to relativize concepts such as logical validity to a language -- a formula is either logically valid in _every_ language that it is well-formed in, or in none of them, so relativizing it to a language would not add any information.

Comment: So _factual_ is just some formula that is true for some values but not for others? Basically what I intuitively think of when I see logical formulas...?

Comment: P.S.: I've also added a bigger excerpt to the image from the book.

Comment: @drozzy - thanks for the Biblio: R.Carnap is there.

Comment: @drozzy - yes; *factual* is a formula like $P \land Q$, that is *satisfiable* (i.e. truth for some truth-assignement) but not L-true (i.e. always true).

Answer (score 3):

To me it looks like the "L" it just an abbreviation of "logical", so the concepts are

- "logically true" (more often called "logically valid", that is, true in all interpretations)
- "logically false" (i.e. contradictory, false in all interpretations)
- "logical implication" (that is, $P_1\to P_2$ is true in every interpretation. Or equivalently: $P_2$ is true in every interpretation, if any, that makes $P_1$ true)
- "logical equivalence"

The prefix is just a way to remind the reader that we're talking about precisely defined technical concepts here, which may or may not align with the reader's *intuition* about how those words ought to be used.

Comment: I can believe this :)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, still not sure why he goes through all this trouble - seems like the usual logical concepts... P.S.: I've included a greater slice from the paper with the surrounding context.